# cannot see print messages in the console using flask

Tags: flask

I am very new to flask. I created a simple http request and it is successfully running. However, it does not show up on my console

I looked up on stack overflow and I tried different methods but they all didnt work, so I decided to post a question

I tried:

```
#login register api
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    print("test")
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    username = request.get_json()['username']
    password = request.get_json()['password']

    cur.execute("SELECT userID, password FROM users WHERE username = '" +
    username + "'")

    mysql.connection.commit()
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    data = {
        'userID': data[0][0],
        'password': bcrpyt.check_password_hash(data[0][1], password)
    }

    return jsonify(data)
```

Also tried

```
#login register api
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    print('This is error output', file=sys.stderr)
    print('This is standard output', file=sys.stdout)
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    username = request.get_json()['username']
    password = request.get_json()['password']

    cur.execute("SELECT userID, password FROM users WHERE username = '" +
    username + "'")

    mysql.connection.commit()
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    data = {
        'userID': data[0][0],
        'password': bcrpyt.check_password_hash(data[0][1], password)
    }

    return jsonify(data)
```

I also noticed when i first run my flask script, i get
Debug mode: off.. Maybe this is the issue why. How do i turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

I am finding it a bit difficult to digest your question, by console, do you mean your web browser or whatever CLI you used to run the flask app?
And yes, by the way, for development, you may turn on debug mode, for production, it's strictly not advisable.
One more thing to note is that if you say your application ran, then it should also show you the link you need to access the app... Usually something like "127.0.0.1:5000", that's not an actually thing by the way just an example.

Comment: The debug mode off or on shouldn't be the reason in any case imo.

Comment: Sorry, I had to do the lengthy write up because you said you are "very new to flask".